# Razor object in a href tag

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new on the area of MVC 4 and Razor.
I am trying to build a Gallarary with "CSS3 Lightbox".
All looks ok but my problem that I cant work with razor and links.
I cant understand what is wrong by the links of pre and next url.
Hope  you can help, I thins maybe something wrong. 
My code looks like that:

```
   @for (var i = 1; i < ViewBag.GallaryItems.Length; i++)
{
<li>
    <a href="#image-@i">
        <img src="@ViewBag.GallaryItems[i].path" />
     <!--   <img src"~/Images/gallary/pic1.jpg" alt="image01"/> -->

        <span>Pointe</span>
    </a>
    <div class="lb-overlay" id="image-@i">
        <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.GallaryItems[i].path)"  />
        <div>
            <h3>@ViewBag.GallaryItems[i].title<span>/point/</span></h3>
            <p>@ViewBag.GallaryItems[i].description</p>
            <a href="#image-@i--" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
            <a href="#image-@i++" class="lb-next">Next</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
    </div>
</li>
       }
```

Comment: What is the error what you get? Try with `href="#image-@(i--)"` and `href="#image-@(i++)"`

Comment: still its looks wrong on the prev its not working the next is ok now. maybe I need to do method on jquiry for this? or its looks ok rightnow?

Comment: Please describe the behaviour you're seeing. "It's not working" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: when image id 2 was opened and click on next the the link image-1 and the prev image-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple didn
href="#image-@(i-1) on prev
 and href="#image-@(i+1) on the next and all works fine now!